# How to fix exception thrown when sending mail message to multiple recipients?

Tags: c#, email, .net-4.0

In the code snippet below, I'm getting a FormatException on 'this.Recipients'. More specifically, the message is "An invalid character was found in the mail header: ';'".

Recipients is a string of three email addresses separated by semicolons (the ';' character). The list of recipients is read from an app.config and the data is making it into the Recipients variable.

How can I be getting this error when multiple recipients should be separated by a semicolon? Any suggestions? As always, thanks for your help!

```
public bool Send()
{
    MailMessage mailMsg = 
       new MailMessage(this.Sender, this.Recipients, this.Subject, this.Message);

    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(SMTP);
    smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

Edit #1 - [This](http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/2.6.aspx) says use a semicolon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't see anything in the [MailMessage constructor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k0ddab0.aspx) to suggest you can specify multiple recipients like that. I suggest you create the `MailMessage` object and then add each email address separately.

Note that the [`MailAddressCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695.aspx%5C) method is documented to accept *comma*-separated addresses... so it's *possible* that that would work in the constructor too.

Comment: Dang interwebs... can't believe everything you read. I found a couple of places where it said you could use semi-colons. I replaced the semicolons with commas and that resolved the issue. Thanks, Jon!

Comment: +1. It takes commas, not semi-colons. Too bad Outlook got us all in the habit of using semi-colons :)

Comment: You can't even trust MSDN. That one says to use semicolons as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webmail.send(VS.99).aspx#

Comment: I have this error on the instantiation or the variable, like this: var msg = new MailMessage(); any thoughts?

Comment: It was the same error for invalid character "@". For some unknown reason the string on the system.net/mail segment of the web.config wasn't encoded on UTF-8. I deleted it and retyped it instead of copy/pasting from a previous project and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the .Add method to add these addresses.  Here is some sample code that I use:

```
string[] toAddressList = toAddress.Split(';');

//Loads the To address field
foreach (string address in toAddressList)
{
    if (address.Length > 0)
    {
        mail.To.Add(address);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reviving this from the dead, if you separate the recipient email addresses by a **comma**, it will work.

```
this.Recipients = "email1@test.com, email2@test.com";

var mailMsg = new MailMessage(this.Sender, this.Recipients, this.Subject, this.Message);
SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(SMTP);
smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpServer.Send(mailMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string[] allTo = strTo.Split(';');
            for (int i = 0; i < allTo.Length; i++)
            { 
                if (allTo[i].Trim() != "")
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(allTo[i]));
            }
```

Comment: How is this different than BiggsTRC's answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
private string FormatMultipleEmailAddresses(string emailAddresses)
    {
      var delimiters = new[] { ',', ';' };

      var addresses = emailAddresses.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

      return string.Join(",", addresses);
    }
```

Now you can use it like

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add(FormatMultipleEmailAddresses("test@gmail.com;john@rediff.com,prashant@mail.com"));
```

Comment: This needs a modification: the `Join` needs `", "` as separator, otherwise an FormatException is still thrown:  
`string.Join(", ", addresses)` works