# How can I send emails to multiple recipients using a MailDefinition

Tags: c#, .net, email

I'm creating a new mail definition using the `CreateMailMessage` function of a `MailDefinition`. One of the required parameters is recipients. The documentation for this function states that recipients is to be a comma-separated list of recipients, however when I try to send a message to multiple users I am getting the following error:

```
An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','...
```

So it seems like this function is not working as intended. Normally I would add all the recipients to the mail message itself, but unfortunately the recipients parameter is required and cannot be left blank. Any ideas?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914481/how-to-fix-exception-thrown-when-sending-mail-message-to-multiple-recipients

Comment: @ken2k Yes I saw that question while searching Google for a solution, and I even attempted to implement my solution using a MailAddressCollection. However I cannot find any way to use a MailAddressCollection with a MailDefinition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working but unfortunately its more of a hack than anything.

I take one email address from the "to" field and set it as the recipient in `CreateMailMessage`, which returns a MailMessage instance.

I take the produced MailMessage and add all the email addresses in my MailAddressCollection by iterating through the construct. I also do this for all CC'd users.